# Powershell,Import-CSV,-Filter SamAccountName

Tags: powershell, csv

Goal:
Trying to search AD against a CSV file with powershell that contains a listing of SamAccountNames. In some cases the SamAccountNames are similar or already in the database and I I want to avoid attempting to create an account that is already in AD. so I need to be able to check first with the -like samaccountname* [notice I need the wildcard].
I can successfully run this command and get the expected results for one user.  What I can't get to work is importing from a CSV file so I don't have to do this search manually for 100 people.

Powershell code:
Get-aduser -filter "SamAccountName -like 'DoeJim*" -Properties * | Format-table SurName,GivenName, Initials,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,Name

So the above command works great for one user search, exactly the output and results I want/need to see, but unable to incorporate the import-csv with the foreach or foreach-object, can't seem to get the correct combination of code. below is what I came up with and does not work
Import-Csv 'c:\import.csv' | foreach {get-aduser -filter samAccountName -like $_."SamAccountName*" -Properties *} | Select SurName,GivenName,Initials,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,Name

Error:
When I run the powershell command, i get the following error:
Get-AdUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'like'.
At line:1 char:154
+...port.csv' | foreach {Get-ADUser -filter SamAccountName -like $_."Sam ...

If someone can provide some hints or guidance as to what I am clearly doing wrong or missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -like "DoeJim*"}` works then the following code snippet gives exactly the same results

```
Import-Csv 'c:\import.csv' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ADUser -filter {sAMAccountName -like "$($_.SamAccountName)*"}
    }
```

Here is used [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#subexpression-operator--):

> Returns the result of one or more statements. For a single result,
>   returns a scalar. For multiple results, returns an array. *Use this
>   when you want to use an expression within another expression.* For
>   example, **to embed the results of command in a string expression**.

Note. Used the `-Filter` syntax pattern from [PowerShell: Filter Results with Active Directory Module Cmdlets](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28485.powershell-filter-results-with-active-directory-module-cmdlets.aspx) article.